# android detect user switching from/to HOME

Tags: android, android-appwidget, homescreen

I have an appwidget at HOME and is updated periodically. I want to stop the update if HOME is not visiable. I use a service to register a screen on/off receiver so as to start/stop updating the appwidget when the screen is on/off. But I don't know how to detect if the screen is on but the user is focusing on something else (i.e. HOME not at foreground). How can I detect if the user switch from/to HOME in my service or receiver (it's an appwidget and I don't have an activity on hand when it happens)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no direct API 
to detect whether HOME is in foreground or background.

But the following snippet will tell you whether the user is currently at HOME or not.

```
if (mActivityManager.getRunningTasks().get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().equals("com.android.launcher") {

//home 

}
```

***DISCLAIMER:*** The above code will work only for the default launcher `(com.android.launcher)`. So, if the user is using some third-party launcher, you can't detect that if you don't know the package name of that launcher.

Comment: What could additionally do is create an exhaustive list of launcher apps by going through the list of installed apps and check for that package along with the default launcher. I know that it sounds really tedious and there will always be some launchers that you missed.

Comment: Thank you Swayam. The coding for me is a bit different. get(0) returns my own task. I need to exhaust the list to find out that my home package name is "com.sonyerricson.home". Others may be different but the method works. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help! Good luck ahead! Cheers! :)